# Can I use a regex and foo.replace() to substitute occurances of a string that aren't in anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use JavaScript to replace target text with a hyperlinked version of the target text. Generally speaking, this is the function in question:

```
    function replace_text_in_editor(target_text, target_type, target_slug) {
        //if target_text was "Google", then the replacement_text might be "<a href="/path/to/google">Google</a>
        var replacement_text = get_replacement_text(target_text, target_type, target_slug);
        if(typeof replacement_text != undefined && replacement_text != '') {
            var content = '';
            content = jQuery( "#content" ).val();
            content = content.replace(target_text,replacement_text)
            if(content != '') {
                jQuery( "#content" ).val(content);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried a couple permutations of the following line, which I'd like to alert to only replace text that's not already hyperlinked.

```
var regex = "/" + target_text + "/";
content = content.replace(regex,replacement_text);
```

Example attempt:

```
var regex = "/^(<a.*?>)" + target_text + "^(<\/a>)/";
```

Can someone please correct me with a regex showing how I should be doing this? No need to explain what the regex does step by step, as I can infer that from the design. Thank you!

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex will cause pain.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), and use a proper parser, or the DOM.

Comment: Can you give source example of what you're searching?  PS: although RE can be problematic with HTML, it's really only when you have nested tags that it starts to break down so don't get too discourage yet....yet.

Comment: @cdhowie Heh, great link. Reading now. @Keng: Example might be link the word Google to "http://google.com" where it is not already linked somewhere.

Comment: My parsing is rather minimal (I'll keep aware of the nested tags issue). From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393017/regular-expression-to-find-text-not-part-of-a-hyperlink, this appears to work for me: `(google)(?!(?:\s*\w*)*</a>)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this but I'm not sure that I compeletly understand.

If you use RE to find the text you can assign it to group $1 by putting `()` around it (in this case "Google").

Then when you go to replace it you build the expression with that group assignment id `$1`

```
\<a href="$1\.com"\>$1\<\/a\>
```

Comment: Example text: `Someting about Google that's linked. Something about Google that's not linked. And the actual <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> link.` The regex `|(<a.*>)(google)(<\/a>)|` matches only the last Google, the one that's linked. I'd like to match all instances of Google except that one.